How to prove that $p^2 + q^2 + r^2 = k^2 + l^2 + m^2$
How to prove that
$$p^2 + q^2 + r^2 = k^2 + l^2 + m^2$$
If I know that
$$ p^2 - k^2 = 2(lm - qr) $$
$$ q^2 - l^2 = 2(km - pr) $$
$$ r^2 - m^2 = 2(kl - pq) $$
By adding the equations side by side, I found that
$p + q + r = k + l + m$ or $p + q + r = - k - l - m$
All variables are the real numbers.
but I don't know what to do with it next.
A friend gave this to me to solve, and I've been working on it for 5 days, but I can't come up with anything.

Hi! I've gotten rid of the worst ambiguity by enclosing your three known facts in double dollar signs $$, but please edit your post to do the same with the other equations. The system is called MathJax. This editing will help prevent your question from being poorly received. Of course, MathJax has a learning curve, but if you make an honest initial attempt, users will generally be happy to help you improve and fix whatever errors you experience.

OK, I see that someone has done it for you, but please do it in advance next time. Thanks!

I am pretty sure this has been answered on the site before, but damn if I can find it.

@DietrichBurde How are you able to deduce that $~2(pq + pr + qr) = 2(kl + kr + qr)~?$

@DietrichBurde Actually, I must confess that I was assuming that all variables were real numbers.  Also, I didn't make that much of an effort to verify your assertion, over the real numbers.  Assuming all variables are real numbers, how do you prove your assertion?

@user2661923 I was first assuming that it is over the integers, see here. But there is no restriction given in the question.

Thanks for your interest, guys! Yes, the variables from the statement are real numbers.

Define:
\begin{align}
   A &= p^2 + 2qr \\
   B &= q^2 + 2pr \\
   C &= r^2 + 2pq
\end{align}
First of all, we can see that $A+B+C$ factors as $(p+q+r)^2$.
Second, and this is a bit more painful, $A^2+B^2+C^2-AB-AC-BC$ factors as $(p^2 + q^2 + r^2 - pq - pr - qr)^2$. I'm going to skip the verification - I got this from Mathematica. Notably, the quantity $p^2 + q^2 + r^2 - pq - pr - qr$ is nonnegative, since it is $\frac{(p-q)^2+(p-r)^2+(q-r)^2}{2}$, so we have $$p^2 + q^2 + r^2 - pq - pr - qr = \sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2-AB-AC-BC}.$$ (This is the step where we rely on $p,q,r$ being real numbers; over the complex numbers, a factor of $\pm1$ would be introduced here.)
But now, we can see that both $p^2 + q^2 + r^2 - pq - pr - qr$ and $(p+q+r)^2 = p^2+q^2+r^2 + 2pq+2pr+2qr$ can be written in terms of $A$, $B$, and $C$. Therefore we can solve for $p^2+q^2+r^2$ and $pq+pr+qr$ individually in terms of $A$, $B$, and $C$: it's a system of two linear equations.
To finish the problem, use the equations we're given, which tell us that
\begin{align}
   A &= p^2 + 2qr = k^2 + 2lm \\
   B &= q^2 + 2pr = l^2 + 2km \\
   C &= r^2 + 2pq = m^2 + 2kl
\end{align}
and that therefore, any function of $p,q,r$ that can be expressed in terms of $A,B,C$ alone is equal to the corresponding function of $k,l,m$. In particular, $p^2+q^2+r^2 = k^2+l^2+m^2$ and, as a bonus, $pq+pr+qr = kl+km+lm$.

Here is a counterexample. For $(p,q,r)=(0,1,2)$ and $(k,l,m)=\frac{1}{3}(-\sqrt{-3}-3,2\sqrt{-3}-3,-\sqrt{-3}-3 )$ the three equations are satisfied, but
$$
p^2+q^2+r^2=5\ne 1=k^2+l^2+m^2.
$$

Dietrich Burde, I think the original poster wants to prove that property on $\Bbb R$, not on $\Bbb C$.

@Angelo I would think it is a Diophantine equation. This would be more natural. But anyway, the OP will edit the post soon, I suppose.

Thanks for your interest, guys!Yes, the variables from the statement are real numbers.
